# How to reverse the order of an already ordered mysql_query

Tags: php

I have a fairly difficult question today and I don't know if it is possible to do, but If it is it would really help me out.  Here is my code:

```
$chatquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conversation 
                          WHERE yourusername='$username' AND 
                          theirusername='$otherchatuser' 
                          ORDER BY ID DESC");

while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($chatquery))
{
    $chatname = $runrows['realuserusername'];
    $chatmessage = nl2br($runrows['message']);
    $chatmessage = preg_replace('/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
                                '<a href="\\1" style="color:#36648B;" target="_blank">\\1</a>', 
                                $chatmessage);

    $chatmessage = preg_replace('/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
                                '\\1<a href="http://\\2" style="color:#36648B;" target="_blank">\\2</a>', 
                                $chatmessage);

    $chatlocation = $runrows['imagelocation'];
    $chatimage = "<img src='$chatlocation' style='width:25px; height:20px;' />";

    echo '<table style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-right:5px;">'.$chatimage.'</td>
                <td><div style="max-width:220px; word-wrap:break-word;">'.$chatmessage.'<div></td>
            </tr>
          </table>';
}
```

This is a chat plugin and right now all of the messages display in `DESC` order, which is what I want.  However what i a m trying to do is if my query gets the same user, `$chatname`, more than once in a row, I want it to display those messages in `ASC` order and not to display the `$chatname` again.  Then, once it gets a different `$chatname` it keeps going in `DESC` order.  So it is like reversing a query.  I do not know if it is possbile but any help would be appreciated.

My last question, based on the response of DaveRandom and using the code he put below.  Where the user name repeats, I would like to have the code

```
$usermessage = '<table><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-right:5px;"></td><td><div style="max-width:220px; word-wrap:break-word;">'.$chatmessage.'<div></td></tr></table>';
```

And where it does not I would like to have

```
    $usermessage = '<table style="margin-bottom:5px;"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-   right:5px;">'.$chatimage.'</td><td><div style="max-width:220px; word-wrap:break-   word;">'.$chatmessage.'<div></td></tr></table>';
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: could you provide a sample output of a conversation showing the ordering result you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order to do this you will have to loop the data twice, once to build the order and once to output the info. For example:

```
function make_row_output ($row, $isRepeated = FALSE) {
  $chatname = $row['realuserusername'];
  $chatmessage = preg_replace(
    array(
      '/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
      '/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i'
    ),
    array(
      '<a href="\\1" style="color:#36648B;" target="_blank">\\1</a>',
      '\\1<a href="http://\\2" style="color:#36648B;" target="_blank">\\2</a>'
    ),
    nl2br($row['message'])
  );
  $chatlocation = $row['imagelocation'];
  $chatimage = "<img src='$chatlocation' style='width:25px; height:20px;' />";
  return ($isRepeated)
    ? '<table><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-right:5px;"></td><td><div style="max-width:220px; word-wrap:break-word;">'.$chatmessage.'<div></td></tr></table>'
    : '<table style="margin-bottom:5px;"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-right:5px;">'.$chatimage.'</td><td><div style="max-width:220px; word-wrap:break-word;">'.$chatmessage.'<div></td></tr></table>';
}

// Do the query
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM conversation
          WHERE yourusername = '$username'
          AND theirusername = '$otherchatuser'
          ORDER BY ID DESC"
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Loop the data and build an ordered array
$last = FALSE;
$rows = $userRows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($last !== FALSE && $row['realuserusername'] != $last) {
    $userRows = array_reverse($userRows);
    echo make_row_output(array_shift($userRows));
    foreach ($userRows as $row2) {
      echo make_row_output($row2, TRUE);
    }
    $userRows = array($row);
  } else {
    $userRows[] = $row;
  }
  $last = $row['realuserusername'];
}

// Last loop to catch any entries still in $userrows
$userRows = array_reverse($userRows);
echo make_row_output(array_shift($userRows));
foreach ($userRows as $row2) {
  echo make_row_output($row2, TRUE);
}
```

Don't forget to [sanitise your database input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)!

Comment: I use mysql_real_escape_string when inputting the data into the datbase.  Is tit better to use it when outputting the data?

Comment: It is not necessary to output the data through this (in fact it will probably break your output) but you should use it on any user input that gets used in a database query. So you may need to escape `$username` and `$otherchatuser`, depending on what they contain and where the data came from. If either of them are a derivative of the user input from the request (i.e. if they came from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE` etc) they should be escaped.

Comment: I have one more question, which I will post in my original post, if you could help me with that then it would be incredible.

Comment: @Eggo The easiest way I can think of to do this is to wrap the output construction in a function. See edit above.

Comment: Sorry for all of these question, but you are so extremely helpful and you can not imagine all that you have helped me.  However, I have one more question and i promise that this is the last.  WHere the function returns ? ' this snipped of code telling that there is a repeated $chatname, how can I get that snippet of code to show '.$chatimage.' once and only once.  In the other one is show it for every row, but here I just want to show it for the first.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Dude you are the most amazing person; thank you so much.  I you want to see what i am working on I can tell you how to view this, however it would require making an account on my website or I could just make one for you and give you the login details if you wanted to see.  Again, thank you so much; you really help me beyond belief here.